# Windows 10 command line "shutdown /l" not working

Tags: windows-10, command-line, shutdown

UPDATE: The problem below arose because I depended on the help information displayed when I entered `shutdown /?`. The command-line help says exactly,

> /l    Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.

The command-line help is incorrect.

The behavior of `shutdown /l` is apparently by design, although if you can set a timeout for actually shutting down or restarting, why not logging off?

---

Using Win10 Home 1909.

I open CMD.
I enter this command:

```
shutdown /l /t 5
```

I expect my session to log out in 5 seconds, but instead nothing happens, except the shutdown command displays its full help file as if I had entered `shutdown /?`.

If I enter other variants, they all work--for example,

```
shutdown /r /t 5
```

causes the computer to restart after 5 seconds.

What's up with this?

Thanks!

Comment: [As per the microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown), /l may not be used with /t or /m switches

Comment: Yep, the timer switches only work with shutdown, sleep, hibernate (not all versions) and restart.

Comment: @T3RR0R I see that in the documentation you referenced. However, I would like to point out that if you enter `shutdown /?` in the CMD window, the documentation says, "/l   Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options." (I copied and pasted that to be sure I didn't miss anything.) It does not mention /t. So I think I fell victim to a "help bug." On the other hand, I would be glad to credit you with the answer if you want to provide one.

Answer (score 0):

My problem with the shutdown command arose because I depended on the help information displayed when I entered `shutdown /?`.

The command-line help says exactly (copied and pasted from the CMD window),

> /l Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.

The [online documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown) says,

> /l    Logs off the current user immediately, with no time-out period. You
> cannot use /l with /m or /t.

The command-line help is incorrect regarding the use of the /t switch.

---

The two sources are also inconsistent regarding the use of the /d switch, but I don't know which one is correct.